# How to detect new lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking on google about this but I can't find a clear answer.

I'm trying to simulate an email, users will insert their text in a textarea and the text will be saved to the database. At a certain point they will come back on that page and they will be able to see their email. So I have to get it from the database.  But how do I detect where the user has a newline as in end of paragraph for example?

Also when I try to alert the text of the email that I retrieved from the database I get the error "Unterminated string literal" and according to google this has to do with the line breaks.

I also know I have to replace the newlines with `\n` the problem is I have to find them first and I cant figure out how.

VB:
This is to get the email and storing it for my view.

```
    Dim GetUserEmail As String = BermudaModuleComponent.GetUserEmail(userId)
    ViewData("myEmail") = GetUserEmail
    Return View()
```

Javascript:
All I do here is alerting my viewdata.

```
var mail = '<%=ViewData("myEmail") %>';
        alert(mail.toString);
```

HTML:
Here I create my textarea.

```
        $('body').prepend('<div class="overlay"></div>');
        $('body').prepend('<div id="welcomeBoxBermuda"><div class="closePopup"></div><span id="send">Send</span><textarea class="EmailText" wrap="hard"></textarea></div>');
```

Comment: No offence but dont think this is a code issue, I will post it though but im pretty sure it wont be much use since there is only this alert.
but okay gimme 2 mins and its there

Comment: shell the output be in the textbox again or as html?
if you put it into the textarea, it should work...

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? You are generating dynamic JavaScript but failing to encode strings properly.

Comment: Yes I am using asp.net, could you clarify that perhaps because im affraid I dont understand you

Comment: Putting it in the textarea gives me the same error.
Only thing I need to know is how to track the white lines so I can replace them with `\n`

Comment: _"I also know I have to replace the newlines with \n the problem is I have to find them first and I cant figure out how."_ - What happens if you use whatever the VB equivalent is for the JS `yourString = yourString.replace("\n", "\\n");` I think it might be something like `yourString = Replace(yourString,Chr(13),"\\n")` (or maybe `Chr(10)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it now, thanks to nnnnnn.

It was `myString.Replace(Chr(10), "\n")`

Thanks a lot all :)

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.
Cant accept it for another 2 days but there are no more answers needed ;)
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try nl2br function and see if you can get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea uses `cr\lf` to break lines so you need to replace `cr\lf` with `\n`. There is a similar topic ['How to handle line breaks when storing textarea entry in a database'](http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/77284-how-handle-line-breaks-when-storing-textarea-entry-database).

Answer (score 0):

```
 \r
```

is new line character in textview. when you save your textview value in database, replace your text view
     \r
character to 
. for example txtmessage is my id for textview, then in code behind use below code to store this value in database :

```
txtmessage.Value.Replace("\r","<br/>")
```

instead of txtmessage.Value.